# CKFinder enable file browser

Tags: php, ckfinder

I installed CKEditor and CKFinder in my site, and when I ran a sample of CKFinder to test the browse image functionality, it is saying:

> The file browser is disabled for security reasons.

I could not find the way of enabling file browser, please can anyone provide the solution?

Comment: Is this a Drupal site by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is why ckfinder.config/php.config exists for.
You should enable ckFinder this way:

```
enabled = "false"
```

and configure your basedirectory according to your files (i.e.)

```
$baseUrl = '/ckfinder/userfiles/';
```

[Another helpful thread.](http://www.fckeditor.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=10714)

Comment: Thanks Thariama for your hint, I observed that the ckfinder is already enabled, and actually found out the solution, by setting the return value to true (originally false) in the function CheckAuthentication() in the ckfinder/config.php file. Though i need to put some logic there, for not allowing all users to upload the files.